# Create custom transition in Corona SDK

Tags: transition, coronasdk

I went through the docs and couldn't find anything.
Is it possible to create a custom transition?
I have to simulate a throw with custom easing etc.
In cocos2d I was able to just create a custom action, with corona I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer is in the docs.

One of the params to transition.to is easing, which can be a custom function.

Comment: I didn't find any docs regarding custom function. Maybe one could back in the day, but right now, your answer seems incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

The docs are quite silent on the topic. However, if you do some trying out, you will find out that a custom easing function takes four parameters (only `nil` from the fifth parameter and up). Some playing around reveals that a custom easing function looks like this:

```
function easer(currentTime, duration, startValue, targetDelta)
    ...
end
```

### Explanation

- `currentTime` / `duration`: `duration` is self-explanatory, and `currentTime` is simply `[0..duration]` during the course of the transition.
- `startValue`: Snapshot of the value at the beginning of the transition.
- `targetDelta`: This is the value of the target-value, minus the `startValue`, i.e. *the distance the easing-function "has to walk"*

### Annotated Example

Say you have the following code:

```
foo.frob = 1
transition.to(foo, {time=1001, frob=0.25})
```

I.e., you want a transition of `foo.frob` of `[1..0.25]`. Then:

```
function easer(currentTime, duration, startValue, targetDelta)
    -- currentTime:  [0..1001]
    -- duration:     1001
    -- startValue:   1
    -- targetDelta:  to-from = 0.25-1 = -0.75

    return startValue + (currentTime/duration) * targetDelta -- a linear interpolator
end
```

### Return Value

The return value should be `startValue` in the beginning, and `startValue+targetDelta` at the end. It is perfectly allowed to leave that range; however, once the transition stops, it automatically becomes `startValue+targetDelta`, so make it `startValue` and `startValue+targetDelta` at the beginning and end.

But you can be creative between the start and end, and let the function bounce back and forth, for example, like some of the included easing functions already do.